# How to interface a pH probe?

Tags: sensor, operational-amplifier

I want to interface a pH probe. The Op-Amp I would like to use is [INA128](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina128.pdf).

My ADC's range is 0 to 5 volts. pH sensor gives a voltage output that is ranged from -0.5 to 0.5 volts, for 0 pH to 14 pH respectively.

Perhaps, I need to give an offset of about 2 volts to Op-Amp and set its gain  to 2. If I do that, will negative voltages be substracted from 2 volts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you need opamps with super low input bias current to interface pH probe. This one has it at 10 nA, that's rather too big. I was able to build one by using opamp with input bias current in femto-amperes range.

You are right about offsetting voltage.

I'd go by finding an opamp which has pH probe interfacing as typical application and implementing the given circuit.

[AD549](http://www.analog.com/en/all-operational-amplifiers-op-amps/operational-amplifiers-op-amps/ad549/products/product.html) is a good candidate

[LMC6001](http://www.ti.com/product/lmc6001) -- I have based my design on this

Comment: so, why i can't do it with ina128?

Comment: As i've said, it's input bias current is too big - it will load the PH probe too much and you will get inaccurate readings. PH probes need very high input impedance opamps to buffer them. You can use high input impedance opamp to buffer it and another opamp to scale/shift the voltage to a level you need. Note, that you will need a split supply for buffer opamp and use noninverting configuration.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you will have to practice proper PCB layout procedures to get anywhere near that claimed femto-ampere input bias current. Leakage across the board surface could easily be an order of magnitude or more larger unless you have proper layout & guard rings.

Comment: The Femtoampere Input Bias Current Electrometer Amplifier ADA4530-1 could be worth a look too.

Answer (score 4):

Like *miceuz* says, what sets a pH sensor apart is its high impedance, which calls for a FET opamp or instrumentation amplifier for minimum error due to input bias current. Next to the parts *miceuz* already mentioned I would add:

[LMC6041](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc6041.pdf): the lowest cost opamp listed at Digikey with input bias current less than 10 fA (2 fA typical).

[INA116](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina116.pdf): the only InAmp listed by Digikey with an input bias current less than 10 fA (3 fA typical, 2 mV offset maximum).

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this after going through my parts bin looking for high impedance opamps. It is possible to get away with a TL081I (30 pA I believe). However, response times are weak so I imagine I'm on the edge of working. I tried it with a 10 nA opamp and it didn't work at all. The lower the better though, and instrumentation amps in general may or may not work. For instance an AD622 didn't work for me but it still has an input bias in the nA range.

Answer (score 0):

LMC6442 works well for me. Gain >2

Comment: That's a useful but rather brief answer to a VERY old question. Can you add a bit more detail with reference to the OP's problem.

Answer (score -4):

I used an AD620, this is not an opamp but a full instrumentation amplifier. Found it on Ebay ;)...

Comment: Perhaps a little more detail, or a schematic, would have helped viewers, rather than the bare statement about the InAmp.